# How do I mock async fetches with jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I've been struggling to figure out how to properly test this code for days :(

```
const request = require('superagent');

const getDog = () => {
  return request.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random');
};

it('resolves', () => {
  // Expect mocked response
});

it('rejects', () => {
  // Expect mocked response
});
```

Comment: Have you tried the method explained in superagent-mock, https://github.com/M6Web/superagent-mock

Comment: I'd like to not use any other libraries other that jest if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases, your code gets some value from API parses it and makes some stuff with it.
As a result, you don't want to make real API call and mock it instead.
There are a couple of ways to do it. One of the possible is to mock the only method on the `superagent` library.

```
// tell jest not to mock superagent because we'll mock the only method
jest.unmock('superagent');

const request = require('superagent');

const getDog = () => {
  return request.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random');
};

it('resolves', () => {
  // mock the get request to resolve object
  request.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
  message: 'Your message'
  });
  // Expect mocked response
  expect.assertions(1);
  return expect(getDog()).resolves.toEqual({
  message: 'Your message'
  });
});

it('rejects', () => {
  // mock the get request to reject object
  request.get = jest.fn().mockRejectedValue({
  message: 'Your error'
  });
  // Expect mocked response
  expect.assertions(1);
  return expect(getDog()).rejects.toEqual({
    message: 'Your error'
  });
});
```

I used `expect.assertions(1)`, there is a [reason](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#expectassertionsnumber):

> This is often useful when testing asynchronous code, in order to make
>   sure that assertions in a callback actually got called.

There are links that can help you:
 [mockFn.mockResolvedValue(value)](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue)
, 
[.rejects](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#rejects)

Comment: I can't seem to get this code working: https://codesandbox.io/s/8xqoozz5j9

Comment: Are you sure, you can run tests in sandbox in this way? 
The error isn't related to tests at all
`regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

Comment: Take a closer look at the code above. And also be aware that these features are available from Jest v23+

Comment: Can't reproduce code on the code sandbox either. But on local machine it works well

Comment: @AlexMiles seems like the issue in jest itself. It says that `unmock` function is undefined. This is PR for new feature in codesandbox.
https://github.com/CompuIves/codesandbox-client/issues/513

Comment: Got it. It worked locally. Thank you!! One thing, it still works if I remove the `unmock`. Is that needed?

Comment: As far as I know, `unmock` mostly related to complex tests, when you want to tell the module system to never return a mocked version of the specified module from `require()` , only real module. Because you could mock it somewhere above.  I'm glad to hear that it helped. Please mark this answer as the solution, I will appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a library such as [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) or [fetch-mock](https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock) to mock out the HTTP response to your request.